# Text box hint and text invisible in authentication UI in Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I start up the sign in activity for my app, it comes up with what *should* appear, with the exception of the text boxes, which have no visible hints. Also, when the user types into the text boxes, the text is invisible (probably same color as the background of the text box]

[This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkqoe.png)

Heres my onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Start the authentication UI
    AuthUIConfiguration config = new AuthUIConfiguration.Builder()
            .userPools(true)
            .backgroundColor(Color.rgb(0x36, 0x89, 0x56))
            .isBackgroundColorFullScreen(true)
            .build();
    SignInActivity.startSignInActivity(this, config);
    LoginActivity.this.finish();

    final IdentityManager identityManager = AWSProvider.getInstance().getIdentityManager();
    // Set up the callbacks to handle the authentication response
    identityManager.login(this, new DefaultSignInResultHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Activity activity, IdentityProvider identityProvider) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                    String.format("Logged in as %s", identityManager.getCachedUserID()),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Go to the main activity
            final Intent intent = new Intent(activity, RangingActivity.class)
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
            activity.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCancel(Activity activity) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And here are the resources I followed to make the activity:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in-customize.html

Thanks